# Stop GNOME from randomizing window locations in its pop-out?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome-panel, favorites

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04, fully patched with `dist-upgrade`. I layout 4 terminals as shown below. The order of the favorite pop-out is top-to-bottom: (a) is (1) top left, (b) is (2) bottom left, (c) is (3) top right, and (d) is (4) bottom right.

[image]

After the favorite pop-out window closes, GNOME will randomize the order. The top-to-bottom order of the pop-out is randomized. (a) in the pop-out may become terminal (3), and (d) in the pop-out may become terminal (1). It is incredibly annoying behavior since I can't quickly jump back to the terminal (1) by clicking the (a) pop-out.

How do I tell GNOME to stop randomizing the window layouts in the favorite pop-out?

---

For me, each terminal is used for a specific task. I usually have 8 or 10 terminals open. I might have Emacs open in Terminal (1), a cp command in terminal (2), and a compiler in terminal (3). I just rotate among them to get the work done.

GNOME's behavior is incredibly annoying because I have to chase down the proper window after its been subjected to their randomization. I swear to Christ I believe they are on drugs for some of the idiotic decision they make. The whole bunch should be drug tested and fired.

---

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

$ apt-cache show ubuntu-gnome-desktop
Package: ubuntu-gnome-desktop
Architecture: amd64
Version: 0.83
Priority: optional
Section: universe/metapackages
Source: ubuntu-gnome-meta
Origin: Ubuntu
...
```

Comment: If you want predictable window management system, usable with keyboard shortcut, did you think about using a tiling windows manager ?